# Storing big amounts of data at frontend

Tags: user-interface, browser, frontend, ag-grid

I have an application, which uses ag-grid to render a big table - more than 100.000 rows. The response from server is shown in developer tools to have 100mb size, but the tab consumes 3GB of RAM after it gets rendered (the page is actually some static elements + vuex + ag-grid table), which leads to browser tab crash.

The user has to have access to every row in the table (to perform some validations), so pagination is not preferred. Also the conflict resolution is a hard part in case of pagination (when someone else changes the content of the page a user looking into)

I have taken a look at local storage and IndexedDB, but looks like they are limited in size, and not guaranteed to be able to store that amount of data.

What are the common patterns to store big amount of data at UI?

Comment: User is not able to view 100 000 rows per screen - its impossible, how about virtual scrolling? to perform some validations - what validations?
when someone else changes the content of the page a user looking into - how avout live updates https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-transactions/?

Comment: Yeah, I think this is too much to display and send. When my grids' data gets to this kind of size, I usually create a search tool, so the user fills in some fields with search terms to restrict the data returned and then that is displayed in the grid.